# Jackson: Serializing/Deserializing generic objects inside single-value arrays via data binding

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm on a team that's using Jackson data binding to handle serialization and deserialization of JSON sent to and from a REST API.  The API widely uses an infamous and difficult-to-deal-with pattern we've dubbed "key values".  The format of the JSON is unfortunately outside of our control, so I'm trying to find a good and easy way to handle serializing and deserializing them on our end.

The key values always appear in the following pattern:

```
"key_name":[{
    "key":"key_name"
    "value":<AN_OBJECT>
}]
```

Notably, they always take the form of an array with a single object inside it, and the value of the key property within the object is always the same as the key of the outer array.  The value can be any valid JSON value, including an array or another object.  The key value itself has no type indicator for the value, but it's always the same type for a given key value and so we specify it in the DTO class.

Ideally, what I would like to have is an easy, repeatable way to serialize and deserialize these properties using data binding.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892306/jackson-serializing-deserializing-string-to-array-with-single-entry) deals with handling a very similar pattern on an individual basis, but since we have many different DTOs that use the pattern, I'd like something that could be used repeatedly.

For example, I'd like to be able to write a DTO class that looked something like this:

```
public class ContactInfo {
    private String id;
    private KeyValue<String> email;
    private KeyValue<String> phone_number;
    private KeyValue<Address> address;

    // Getters and setters

    public static class Address {
        private String street;
        private String city;
        private String state;
        private String zip;

        // Getters and setters
    }
}
```

and have it be able to serialize and deserialize via data binding JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "id":"123456",
    "email":[{
        "key":"email",
        "value":"fakeperson@example.com"
    }],
    "phone_number":[{
        "key":"phone_number",
        "value":"1-555-555-1234"
    }],
    "address":[{
        "key":"address",
        "value":{
            "street":"123 Main Street",
            "city":"New York City",
            "state":"NY",
            "zip":"12345
        }
    }]
}
```

We already have a solution which works for String key values, but I ran into trouble when attempting to generalize it to work non-string key value objects.

---

The existing classes look like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = KeyValueSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = KeyValueDeserializer.class)
public class KeyValue {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    // Omitted getters and setters...
}

public class KeyValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<KeyValue> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(KeyValue keyValue, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("label", keyValue.getKey());
        jgen.writeStringField("value", keyValue.getValue());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}

public class KeyValueDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<KeyValue> {

    protected KeyValueDeserializer() {
        super(KeyValue.class);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String value = node.findValue("value").asText();
        String key = node.findValue("key").asText();
        return new KeyValue(key, value);
    }

}
```

When attempting to generalize this class, I ran into trouble with the type and deserialization.  I tried using something like this in the custom deserializer:

```
objectMapper.readValue(valueNode.traverse(), objectMapper.getTypeFactory()
    .constructParametricType(TypedKeyValue.class, type)));
```

but I have no idea how to determine what the the expected type should be.

In addition to the custom serializer and deserializer, I also looked into using the I looked into using the "UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS" deserialization feature.  However, we're using a shared framework that has the deserializer inside of it to access the API and I don't want to enable that flag for everyone since only our team is working with this particular API.  I also couldn't find a way to only enable that flag for a specific class or property.

---

So, my question is, is there a way to do what I want?  I don't necessarily need to use custom serializers and deserializers or generics, but the solution needs to be something that can be easily added and maintained within a large number of DTOs, and so I don't want to have lots of per-class code or repeated wrapper classes if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom serializer/deserializer. Just use classes that reflect the structure of your JSON, along with the [`@JsonCreator` annotation on the constructor](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#using-constructors-or-factory-methods).

Your `KeyValue` class could be modelled as a list of `KeyValueElement`s:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyValue<T>
    extends LinkedList<KeyValueElement<T>> {

    public KeyValue() {
    }

    public KeyValue(String key, T value) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(1);
        map.put(key, value);
        KeyValueElement<T> elem = new KeyValueElement<>(map);
        this.add(elem);
    }
}
```

I've provided 2 constructors: one for Jackson (the one with no-args), and another one to ease the key-value pair creation. **The correctness of the generated JSON will depend on how you instantiate this class.**

The `KeyValueElement` class might be modelled as follows:

```
public class KeyValueElement<T> {

    private String key;

    private T value;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @JsonCreator
    public KeyValueElement(Map<String, Object> delegate) {
        this.key = (String) delegate.get("key");
        this.value = (T) delegate.get("value");
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, simply use your `ContactInfo` class, without any annotations. Here's a test:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(
    PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);

String json = "{\"id\":\"123456\",\"email\":[{\"key\":\"email\",\"value\":\"fakeperson@example.com\"}],\"phone_number\":[{\"key\":\"phone_number\",\"value\":\"1-555-555-1234\"}],\"address\":[{\"key\":\"address\",\"value\":{\"street\":\"123 Main Street\",\"city\":\"New York City\",\"state\":\"NY\",\"zip\":\"12345\"}}]}";

ContactInfo contactInfo = mapper.readValue(json, ContactInfo.class);

String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(contactInfo);

System.out.println(json.equals(serialized)); // true
```

The idea is to let your classes reflect your JSON's structure, so that your `KeyValue<T>` is actually a `List<KeyValueElement<T>>` (with only one element), with `KeyValueElement<T>` being a simple key-value pair.

The "tricky" part is to let Jackson know how to deserialize every `KeyValueElement<T>`. This is when the `@JsonCreator` annotation comes in handy and does its magic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The unmodified solution isn't quite what I needed, but it gave me a good starting point.  What I needed was to abstract away the "list" portion of the KeyValue (because the lists always have exactly one value inside them, making them useless clutter).  I was able to modify your class by adding in forwarding methods to access the inner element, and tagging them with @JsonIgnore

Comment: @Pausbrak I'm glad my answer was useful, at least as a starting point. Yours is not an easy problem...

Comment: Edited my previous comment